# How to call a method that creates a JFileChooser dialog from a different class

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have been trying to call a method in another class that instantiates a new JFileChooser dialog. Everything seems to work ok except that the APPROVE_OPTION code

```
        int userSelection = chooser.showSaveDialog(chooser);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("File saved " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }
```

doesn't appear to work.
Below is the method contains the createFile method that has the JFileChooser within

```
public class TextFileHandler {

private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
private static JFileChooser chooser;
private static int userSelection;



public void createFile(String shiftPattern) {

    chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(shiftPattern + "_export"));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Save shift pattern to CSV format");
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV", "csv");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int userSelection = chooser.showSaveDialog(chooser);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("File saved " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }

}
```

The below file is an excerpt of the class that calls the above method from a button press action.

```
else if (action.equals("EXPORT_CSV_BUTTON")) {

        TextFileHandler textFile = new TextFileHandler();
        String temp = copyPatternController.getShiftPatCode();

        messageShow(new Integer(TextFileHandler.getUserSelection()).toString() + " and "
                + (TextFileHandler.getChooser().APPROVE_OPTION)); //for debugging

        textFile.createFile(temp);


            FileWriter fw = null;
            try {
                File file = new File(temp + "_export.csv");

                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.append("testing");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in writing csv file !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try {
                    fw.flush();
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

The save dialog appears ok but when i press save the dialog closes and nothing is created. Appreciate any ideas

Comment: Just a remark: `new Integer(TextFileHandler.getUserSelection()).toString() + " and " + (TextFileHandler.getChooser().APPROVE_OPTION)` is an unbelievable obfuscated way to express `TextFileHandler.getUserSelection() + " and " + JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`. Besides that, your issue is that you have declared a local variable `int userSelection` that hides the field `TextFileHandler.userSelection`. Modifications of the local variable don’t affect the field. As an additional side note, you should stop your habit of declaring every field `static`. Think about what it means and when it’s appropriate

Answer (score 0):

In the EXPOPRT_CSV_BUTTON I was missing a getSelectedFile() call.

```
File file = new File(TextFileHandler.getChooser().getSelectedFile().getPath() + ".csv");
```

The creates the file with no problems. I have also refactored my obfuscated code thank you for pointing that out.